# Thinkpad T480 not taking a charge anymore

Tags: 18.04, battery, thinkpad

**Update**

And, now with no explanation, it's working...

[image]

**Update**

Now I don't get a charge at all:

[image]

Any help would be incredible. I've got through the power reset, remove battery, check connections and all that. Doesn't seem to help. Tried different outlets, lol, and lots of other random things. No luck.

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 on a Thinkpad T480, but some time ago it stopped utilizing my extra battery.

I'd love some help getting it back in action.

[image]

Comment: And now it's just stuck at 5%, not moving at all.

Comment: Next thing to try: Replace battery. Does it charge with computer shut down?